# Complexity of adding new element to std::list

Tags: c++

What is a complexity of inserting new element in STL list using insert() method? Is it always O(1)? If not, what depends on it? Can we say that adding new element to the list using push_front() and push_back() is always very fast with complexity O(1)?

Comment: [This `std::list` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) should be helpful.

Comment: See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert#Complexity).  `insert`ing a single element is O(1) because you have to give an iterator for the insert location.  However, finding that iterator could be up to O(N) depending on where you want to put the new element.

Comment: fwiw, constant complexity is not necessarily fast. Compare adding an element taking 20 seconds vs adding an element that takes 1 second per already inserted element into a list of 10 elements. Btw, inserting into a list is constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is a complexity of inserting new element in STL list using insert() method?

O(1).

> Is it always O(1)?

Yes. Always.

> Can we say that adding new element to the list using push_front() and push_back() is always very fast

Maybe. "Very fast" is subjective. It probably isn't as fast as pushing to the front of `std::deque` on average, but it probably is faster than compiling the LLVM project from scratch.

> with complexity O(1)?

Yes.

Comment: Does O(1) means that inserting new element always takes the same amount of time?

Comment: @michalt38 O(1) means that "N" doesn't influence the number of operations. What "N" we are considering can vary, but conventionally it is the number of elements in the container.